# VBA script in excel to find and highlight text

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a VBA script that will help me find certain keywords in a cell and if found highlight the entire row. Below are my requirements:

I have a database of words eg hell, get out, shut up, don't you dare etc. I need a macro to search the data in column "E" of excel and in case any of the cell in column "E" contains any word listed in the database (irrespective of the case of the word upper or lower)the entire row is highlighted. The word can be in the beginning, middle or end of the cell and the macro should be able to find that word and highlight the column.

Seeking help from all VBA masters for this.

Comment: Hi there.  Can you please post what you have tried? "Code this for me" kind of questions are generally frowned upon around here, however,  we'd love to help you learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional formatting, instead of VBA.

Conditional formatting works by applying a 'second formula' to a given cell. If the 'second formula' results in TRUE, then special formatting conditions can be applied.

**EXAMPLE CONDITIONAL FORMATTING**

For example, if you have a single column of Data, A:A, and you want to check if that column has the exact string "hello world", you could add a conditional format [Home ribbon, Styles section, Conditional Formatting] that turns a cell yellow with this formula:

```
=$A1="hello world"
```

This will only result in TRUE if the cell in column A at that row equals exactly "hello world" [note that Column A has an absolute-reference $, and row 1 does not, so row 1 is relative to the position of the cell in the condiitonal format rule].

To check to see if any row in column A *includes* hellow world, we need to add a SEARCH function, which checks to see if a small search string is inside of a larger string:

```
=SEARCH("hello world",$A1)>0
```

Because SEARCH by default returns the first character in a larger string that matches the search term (and if it finds nothing, it returns #N/A), we check to see if our search for "hello world" in column A returns a number.

**SEARCHING MULTIPLE COLUMNS**

Now, to see if ANY column, say from A-D, *includes* "hello world", we concatenate each value of each column so that it gives us a single string, which we can search through for "hello world", like so:

```
=SEARCH("hello world",$A1&$B1&$C1&$D1)>0
```

This will first create a single string, equal to A1 & B1 & C1 & D1 all in a row. Then it will search that newly created string to see if "hello world" is inside it, and return a number value if it is.

**ARRAY FORMULA BASICS**

Finally, we need to do the tricky part - searching for multiple terms instead of just "hello world". This is called an Array Formula. An array formula works by performing a single operation on multiple cells, and then returning multiple results in an Array. In an Excel sheet, an array formula must be confirmed with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER (instead of just ENTER), but in conditional formatting, you actually don't need to do anything special - it will recognize an array formula without a special command.

As an example of conditional formatting, see this example, which checks whether any value from A1:A5 = 10, and if it does, it gives us the value in B1:B5:

```
=IF(A1:A5=10,B1:B5,"")
```

Remember in Excel on a worksheet, this would be confirmed by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. If you do test this, it will give you the following result, assuming A2 = 10 and A5 = 10:

```
={"";B2;"";"";B5}
```

This result would actually be hidden, because Excel can't "collapse" an array function on its own. So assume column B had values, and we actually want to sum them together. We would then wrap the Array formula in a SUM function:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5=10,B1:B5,""))
```

As you can see if you test this, we have actually created our own SUMIF function, using Array formulas instead of the built-in SUMIF.

**SEARCHING FOR MULTIPLE TERMS WITH ARRAY FORMULAS**

So now we apply these principles to the conditional formatting, to create an array formula which will check our concatenated 'NEW STRING' for any number of provided terms, as follow [Assumes the search terms are typed into cells E1:E10]:

```
=SUM(SEARCH($E$1:$E$10,$A1&$B1&$C1&$D1)>0)
```

This formula can be placed as a conditional formatting rule which reaches all of A:D. Set the rule to highlight / change format in whatever way you like.